# How to delete unique records in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

```
rowID | StudentName | rollNo | Class
      |             |        |
1     | ABC         |10      |  5   
2     | ABC         |10      |  5
3     | xyz         |11      |  5
4     | asd         |12      |  5
```

how can i delete all the `unique` records where class is `5`

so that i have remaining table as

```
rowID | StudentName | rollNo | Class
      |             |        |
1     | ABC         |10      |  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select min(id), StudentName, rollNo, Class
from t
where class = 5
group by StudentName, rollNo, Class
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you actually want to *delete* the records, then you need to use `delete`:

```
delete t
    from t left join
         (select studentname, rollno, class, min(id) as min_id, count(*) as cnt
          from t
          group by studentname, rollno, class
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.minid and tt.cnt > 1
    where tt.minid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1
        INNER JOIN
    table t2 
WHERE
    t1.rowID < t2.rowID AND t1.StudentName = t2.StudentName and t1.rollNo=t2.rollNo
```

this deletes all duplicate rows leaving the one with highest `rowID`